# Code to keep the command window open after code finishes executing

Tags: c#

So I’m learning about C# with visual Studio, I wrote a small program kind of like a “hello world”,
I remember that with C++ md Java there is a conman you wrote at the end of your code o hav the command window stay on after the program finishes running. My question is, or C#, what is that code or command I’m supposed to write so that when I debug it and it runs the command window doesn’t closes after I finish with he user input?

Comment: Please take a moment and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Your content is good, but you should always include the code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue... ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

This will keep window open until you press **Enter** key

Comment: Thank you now the window stays open and I can see my input an output! Thank you very much!